# How I do a Bluetooth auto pairing?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on Android Studio, doing an app with 2 activities. In the first one, you can scan near devices and when you touch some device, the app change to the next activity. If the device hasn't been paired before, the connection fail or the app crashed. Im not sure the order of the Broadcast and the createBond

I tried putting createBond() after setPairingConfirmation()

```
 private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver5 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST)) {
            try {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // int pin=intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_KEY", 0);
                // the pin in case you need to accept for an specific pin
                int pin = intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_KEY",CONTRASEÑA);
                Log.d(TAG, "Start Auto Pairing. PIN = " +intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_KEY",CONTRASEÑA));
                byte[] pinBytes;
                // pinBytes = (""+pin).getBytes("UTF-8");
                pinBytes = ("" + pin).getBytes("UTF-8");
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    device.setPin(pinBytes);
                    device.setPairingConfirmation(true);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurs when trying to auto pair");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

 private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener =
        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // Se detiene discovery porque es muy intenso para la memoria
        mBTAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: clickeaste sobre un dispositivo");
        String deviceName = mBTDevices.get(arg2).getName();
        String deviceAddress = mBTDevices.get(arg2).getAddress();

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceName = " + deviceName);
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceAddress = " + deviceAddress);

        // Crea el enlace
        // NOTA: se requiere api 17 o más
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            // Entra si la versión del SDK es mayor a versión Lollipop
            Log.d(TAG, "Tratando de emparejar con: " + deviceName);
            mBTDevices.get(arg2).createBond();
        }

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver5,intentFilter);

        Intent i = new Intent(DispositivosBT.this, MainActivity.class); //
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, deviceAddress);

        startActivity(i);
    }
};
```

Now, when I try to connect to an unpair device, sometimes the app stop working, and other timer, the connection fails but the app continue working and if I try again to connect, the connection success.
I need to connect the an unpair device and change to the next activity

Comment: I have solved my problem. I put the function startActivity() in an if conditional which evaluate if a bond does exist.

Comment: can you show your final code? i need it

Comment: Any results there? I need it too

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found was this one:

```
   private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener =
                    new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
                        cancelarDiscovery(mBTAdapter);

                        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: clickeaste sobre un dispositivo");
                        String deviceName = mBTDevices.get(arg2).getName();
                        deviceAddress = mBTDevices.get(arg2).getAddress();

                        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceName = " + deviceName);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceAddress = " + deviceAddress);

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to pair with: " + deviceName);
                            mBTDevices.get(arg2).createBond();
                        }

                        if(mBTDevices.get(arg2).getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                            nextActivity();
                        }
                      }
                };
```